# Create Java Set from JSON arrays

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

Is there any way to set `ObjectMapper`'s default behaviour to create Java `Set` instead of `List` from JSON arrays

**UPDATE**

Let me add some details about my problem

My data is the recursive structure, the field `params` might appear multiple times in the recursive JSON. In my Java model, I have the corresponding field `Map<String, Object> params`. The values of this map may vary - one of the possible is JSON array. By default List is created, my goal is to switch it to Set.

**UPDATE 2**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Group.class, name = "group"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Value.class, name = "value")
})
public interface Node {
    String getType();
}

public class Group implements Node {
    List<Node> content;
}

public class Value implements Node {
    String name;
    Map<String, Object> params;
}
```

Possible JSON

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "params": {
        "ids": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5"
        ]
      },
      "type": "value"
    },
    {
      "name": "SUM",
      "params": {
        "sum": 400
      },
      "type": "value"
    }
  ],
  "type": "group"
}
```

my current code is

```
String content = "json-here";
Node node = objectMapper.readValue(content, Node.class);
```

**UPDATE 3** (minimal reproducible example):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Group.class, name = "group"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Value.class, name = "value")
})
interface Node {
    String getType();
}

class Group implements Node {
    private List<Node> content;

    public void setContent(List<Node> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Group{" +
                "content=" + content +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "group";
    }

}

class Value implements Node {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> params;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setParams(Map<String, Object> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", params=" + params +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "value";
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String content = """
                         {
                           "content": [
                             {
                               "name": "ID",
                               "params": {
                                 "ids": [
                                   "1",
                                   "2",
                                   "3",
                                   "4",
                                   "5"
                                 ]
                               },
                               "type": "value"
                             },
                             {
                               "name": "SUM",
                               "params": {
                                 "sum": 400
                               },
                               "type": "value"
                             }
                           ],
                           "type": "group"
                         }
                """;
        Node node = objectMapper.readValue(content, Node.class);

        System.out.println(node);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe https://www.javaguides.net/2019/04/jackson-list-set-and-map-serialization-and-deseialization-in-java-example.html helps

Comment: Maybe it is much better understandable with sample data and expected result and the code you have tried

Comment: sample data added

Comment: What happens if you change `List<Node> content;` to `Set<Node> content;`?

Comment: good question, I need Set only for `params` values actually

Comment: so you want to have a `Map<String, Set<String>> params` there?

Comment: @cyberbrain Yes, for arrays, but there are possible other types like Integer in my example

Comment: it's "hard" for me to reproduce the problem and try a solution, as you didn't provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You could do the conversion yourself in a setter

```java
public class Group implements Node {
    private Set<Node> content;

    public void setContent(List<Node> content) {
       this.content = content == null ? null : new LinkedHashSet<>(content);
    }
}
```

I think Jackson also supports deserializing `Iterable`... so it might be slightly less garbage collection to do.

```java
public class Group implements Node {
    private Set<Node> content;

    public void setContent(Iterable<Node> content) {
       if (content == null) {
          this.content = null;
       } else {
          this.content = new LinkedHashSet<>(); 
          content.forEach(this.content::add);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such feature out of the box and I believe there isn't, because `Set` allows only unique elements, while Json Array can contain duplicates.

Still, you can achieve this with custom deserializer for `Object` (if there is a way to configure jackson through `DeserializationConfig`, I am not aware of it).

```
public class CustomObjectSerializer extends StdDeserializer<Object> {

  public CustomObjectSerializer() {
    super(Object.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    JsonNode root = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
    return switch (root.getNodeType()) {
      //MISSING is jackson specific type, you may need different handling
      case NULL, MISSING -> null;
      //Add array values in Set
      case ARRAY -> handleJsonArrayAsSet(root, context);
      //We don't know the exact numeric type, so let jackson handle it
      case NUMBER -> context.readTreeAsValue(root, Number.class);
      //Classic dynamic object, represented as Map
      case OBJECT -> context.readTreeAsValue(root, Map.class);
      //String value
      case STRING -> root.asText();
      //Boolean value
      case BOOLEAN -> root.asBoolean();
      //Types in json specification are covered
      //Don't care about the rest atm, which are jackson specific
      default -> throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected value: " + root.getNodeType());
    };
  }

  private Set<Object> handleJsonArrayAsSet(JsonNode node, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    Set<Object> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (JsonNode element : node) {
      Object value = context.readTreeAsValue(element, Object.class);
      set.add(value);
    }
    return set;
  }
}
```

Register the deserializer and example:

```
public class RandomStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(Object.class, new CustomObjectSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    String json = """
            [
              1,
              1,
              "2",
              {
                "key1": "val",
                "key2": 11,
                "key3": true,
                "key4": [1, 2, 3]
              }
            ]
            """;
    Object result = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
    System.out.println(result.getClass());
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```